# MongoDB java and exception

Tags: java, mongodb, exception

I've tried to handle MongoDB exceptions with java driver, but in none of my try catch exception are thrown ?

```
try
{
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB database = client.getDB("example");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: do you have mongo service running?

Comment: Mongo runs in a docker container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch exception when creating MongoClient instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813060/how-to-catch-exception-when-creating-mongoclient-instance)

Comment: Non-existing databases and collections are automatically created on use if you have the required permission.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get your exception with your first query:

```
    try
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB database = client.getDB("example");
        database.getCollection("foo");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: getDB is deprecated, use getDatabase

Comment: I've tried     public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            MongoClient mongoClient=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
            mongoClient.getDatabase("davidyannickdb");
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Erreur");
        }
    } but my exception is not handled

Comment: shutdown your mongod, try to get a collection (like foo in my code) and you'll see the exception